# Why this keyword is not referring to window in a stand alone JS function

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I was just trying scoping and this keyword in JS, While writing the below code i really got confused as i was expecting `console.log(a)` after calling `f()` to be `5`, but instead it gave me `10`.

My question is :

1. Isn't the `this` keyword in a standalone function refers to `window` ?
2. If yes, then isn't the code inside the function is the same as `window.a = 5`
   and the value of `a` should be updated to `5`?
3. If no, why `console.log(this)` results in window, but value of `a` (which
   is global) isn't updated ?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fwbbdLxx/)

```
var a = 10;

function f(){
    this.a = 5;
    console.log(a);
}

console.log(a);
f();
console.log(a);
```

Comment: I tried this in a standalone page (not JSFiddle), and got 5 for the second one.

Answer (score 9):

If the code is run in global scope, then it will produce the result you expect. The problem with your jsFiddle is that it does *not* run in global scope. Hence `var a;` creates a *local* variable `a`, while `this.a` refers to the *global* variable `a`.

Here is your code run in global scope: http://jsfiddle.net/grayoork/ (note the "no wrap - ...") setting.

Reference: [MDN - `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

---

So both `var a;` and `this.a` will refer to the same variable iff:

- the code runs in global scope
- `this` inside `f` refers to the global object, which is the case if

  - `f` is executed as `f()` and not bound, or it is bound to the global object
  - `f` is not in strict mode.

Comment: that mean both "a" inside function and outside function referring the same variable rite ?

Comment: I have one more doubt, this keyword outside in the global context(not in function) refers to the window rite ? lets say i declared a var a=10; a is a global variable and bound to window. why can't i access it like this window.a //undefined

Comment: You can: http://jsfiddle.net/3ueq6oye/. You are probably doing the same mistake again and are not running the code in global scope.

Answer (score 1):

This is unique to JSFiddle, due to the fact that they wrap their functions. If you use Chrome's console, and click on the file it's being logged from, you get something other than your code. Here's the actual JS that's being executed:

```
window.onload=function(){
var a = 10;

function f(){
    this.a = 5;
    console.log(this);
}

console.log(a);
f();
console.log(a);


}
```

Now it's clear what's going on - `a` isn't global at all! It's scoped to the onload function.

Answer (score 0):

this refers to the current context - see the javascript call and apply functions which can switch contexts
within a function this refers to the function unless the function was called in such a way as to set the context eg someobject.function() or through the use of call or apply

Answer (score -1):

If `this` is used inside a function it's scope is only for that function. So `var a = 10;` and `this.a = 5` are two different variables.

Comment: this is not correct, the value of this will change depending on how the function is called